# Get Files and Folders by Folder and File wildcard

Tags: c#, .net, regex, file, path

I have a pattern like `..\\*\\your_magic*.txt*zip` and I'm in Directory "x"

now I would love to get all files and directories that match the above pattern.

For example if I'm in 
    `d:\test\test1` 
valid results would be: (lets assume the folders and files do exist)

```
d:\test\test1\your_magic.txt.zip
d:\test\test1\your_magic.txtzip
d:\test\test2\your_magic.txt.zip
d:\test\test1\test3\your_magic.txt.zip
```

What I'm thinking, is that I would need to split up the string into folders and search all of them recursively. Now I'm not a c# pro and hope that there will be a much more simple solution.

Comment: Yep.. you need to use recursion unless those files are being kept track of when they are created,  otherwise it has no way of knowing

Answer (score 0):

See [`Directory.GetFiles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"d:\test", "your_magic*.txt*zip", SerachOption.AllDirectories);
```

Comment: i was there already, however i cant just use it like that:
    `string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"..\*\", "your_magic*.txt*zip", SerachOption.AllDirectories);`

also, what about strings like: `..\\*\\your_magic*` as this can be both, a directory or a file

Comment: @HannesAnders Any particular reason why not?